# Which "book(s)" complements "Combinatorial Problems and Exercises by László Lovász"?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am trying to prepare for my entrance exam/interview to an Integrated-Master's and PhD programme in Mathematics in my country.

Currently, I am an undergraduate student.

I have been told that "Combinatorial Problems and Exercises by László Lovász" is a book one must master before one may consider oneself to be a strong PhD/Masters candidate in the field of combinatorics.

So, could anyone please guide me with regards to which books I could follow in order to learn the theory required to solve the problems in this book?

I have only just developed a fascination for combinatorics (**I am a first year undergraduate student**). Hence, it would be very helpful if anyone could provide a list of books that begin at the introductory level.

Thank you!

(I don't know why this question was closed? There are many such soft-questions on stackexchange. Furthermore, how else will a person who has no access to high-quality resources as those in the developed world know from where to study, unless such questions are asked.

Please reconsider and open the question.)

Comment: I do agree with your edit, but SE is not really a place for book recommendation post (to my knowledge). This kind of question was allowed in past. Also in this kind post you will likely going to get answers/recommendation in comments. So restricting answer don’t affect much. I’m pretty sure combinatorial book resource already exists on this site. Good luck with your study.

Comment: Ok. No worries. Thank you for considering my plea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions listed here:

- "A Course in Combinatorics" by J.H. van Lint and R.M. Wilson
- "Introduction to Combinatorics" by Martin J. Erickson
- "Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science" by Ronald
  L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik
- "Enumerative Combinatorics" by Richard P. Stanley
- "Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms" by Peter J. Cameron

Comment: Thank you so much. I, however, am in my first year of my undergraduate studies. So, could you please tell me from which of the above books should I begin? Could you please divide the list into "introductory", "intermediate", "advanced"? Should I solve each book cover to cover?

Comment: your welcome, as an introductory reference I strongly recommend you to study this one not listed above: 
"Aspects of Combinatorics: A Wide-ranging Introduction" by Victor Bryant. 

all the above-mentioned books are in  "intermediate" level in my opinion.

Comment: Hi, I have gone through the book by Victor Bryant. This is a great book, but since I have Olympiad Problem Solving experience, the contents of the book are familiar to me. What should I study next? Any book that is of similar rigour level but deals with different topics will be great. Also, have you solved Lovasz' book?

Comment: please answer above

Comment: the "Stanley" book may be best for next choice. keep in mind that no two book contain entirely different topics. I think better way for you is two go through multiple books and study topics in a selective manner .